# Android Live TV streaming

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

This application is for live tv streaming. When I run this, it says "sorry this video can not be played".

Here is the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView player = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.player);
    String httpLiveUrl = "http://aj.lsops.net/live/aljazeer_en_high.sdp/playlist.m3u8";
    //for Android 2.3.3 I used httplive:// prefix
    player.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
    player.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    player.requestFocus();
    player.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<VideoView
android:id="@+id/player"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the logcat:
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: did you check if the url is accessable? I tried to load it in chrome but it return website unavailable err

Comment: Yes, you are right. Can you give me a address, that I can access it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Did you try to reach the URL through your Browser. I haven't been able to ping it. The URL might have changed.

Comment: you are right. Is there anyother link that I will able to run?

Comment: Try with this URL: `http://wpc.6d40.edgecastcdn.net/806D40/Wowza3/live-origin/gtv132.stream/chunklist.m3u8`

Comment: I can not access it in browser. It says in browser "403 - Forbidden"